# JQuery Checkbox list problem in IE? Values saved as on,on,on should be 10,12,13 etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, checkbox

I've a list of checkboxes that get rendered out using javascript.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sportType"  id="sportType11" value="11" />Golf
<input type="checkbox" name="sportType"  id="sportType12" value="12" />Tennis
<input type="checkbox" name="sportType"  id="sportType13" value="13" />Football
<input type="checkbox" name="sportType"  id="sportType14" value="14" />Cricket
```

On submitting the form I can pickup the selected values in ASP.NET by using:

```
Request.Form["sportType"]
```

In firefox this works and returns something like 11,12,13,14 (Assuming all are checked)

In IE however it returns on,on,on,on

Has anyone encountered this before and hopefully solved it?

Thanks

---

Having dug a little deeper I've discoved that in IE Jquery render the input box like so:

```
<input propdescname="sportType" id="sportType11" type="checkbox" jQuery1288622120804="10" value="on"/>
```

Which give explains the on,on,on value thats been retured? Can anyone shed any light on how to correct this, I assume jquery does this so it can consistantly keep track of selected checkboxes.

Thanks

Kevin

---

**Solved, kind of**

[Value of jQuery generated checkbox in IE8 is stored as "on" rather than actual value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071289/jquery-1-4-checkbox-ie8-doesnt-return-values-values-stored-as-on-rather-than/4072164#4072164)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name to name="sportType[]" and see what happens, what I would do in PHP at least.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it doesnt work I'm affraid. I've just discoved it seems to be a jquery error rather than an IE specific.

Comment: That naming convention is very PHP specific, I don't know any other language that does it that way.