# JQuery change method in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

```
$("[propertyname]").change(function()
        {
            if($(this).attr("propertyname") == "Fees.ProfitAmount") {
                if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").val() == 29751)
                {
                    FormatAsMoney(this, 10000000000, true); 
                }
            }
            UpdateField(this, false);
            if($(this).attr("propertyname") == "Fees.CalculationSource") {
                SetFixedRate();
            }
            if($(this).attr("propertyname") == "FloatingComponent.IndexID") {
                FillIndexDescription();
                UpdateResetEnabled();
            }
            if($(this).attr("propertyname") == "FloatingResetType" ||  
                $(this).attr("propertyname") == "ResetDay" ||
                $(this).attr("propertyname") == "ResetDayComponent.RateResetFrequency")
            {
                UpdateResetEnabled();
            }
            SetSaveAsNew(this);
        });
```

Specifically the money formatting doesn't take place in IE, but I can see it being called in Firefox.

The above works in Firefox but not IE7 or IE8, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: " money formatting doesn't take place in IE". Can you be more precise to where it stops?  `$("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").val() == 29751` is true ? Is the function `FormatAsMoney` called (place an alert inside).

Comment: Nope format as money isn't called in IE, i placed alerts. It gets there and works fine in FF though. 99% sure it's an issue with the .change() method. Does JQuery's change not work in IE?

Comment: Does it get as far as the if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").val() == 29751) block in IE?

Comment: No it does not. The alert was right above the Format as money call.

Comment: seems like right here it doesn't work : if($(this).attr("propertyname") == "Fees.ProfitAmount")

Comment: If there is a lot of element, you may try : `$("[propertyname]").each().change`

Comment: I'm binding a change event, not changing every value on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have stumbled upon [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071289/jquery-1-4-checkbox-ie8-doesnt-return-values-values-stored-as-on-rather-than).

When checking the *value* of a checkbox, IE will return "on" rather than "29751". To see the actual *value* you need to use `attr("val")` instead, like so:

```
if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val") == 29751)
```

Comment: It's failing before the val() however =/

Comment: this is SOOOO weird. When I alert $("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val") in IE, I get 29751. However, when I try and do the compare and alert right after it, I don't see the alert.....