# jquery IE9 checkbox form serialize returns "on"

Tags: jquery, jsonserializer

In FF this works fine:

```
<div id="conditionAssociationList" class="clearfix">
<input id="a0_1681" type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1681">
<label for="a0_1681" name="cb">Chocolate</label>
...
</div>
```

...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",    
    data: $("#EntryForm").serialize() + "&id=" + id ,
```

...

in my web service i will get an argument of cb with a comma delimited array list of all the selected check box values.

However, in IE9, I get an argument of cb with a comma delimited array list of "on".

Anyone know of a work around for this?

Comment: I tried your code in IE9, and it seems to work fine, I get '&cb=1681'. Can you show some more code maybe?

Comment: Is this not the same problem?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069598/jquery-checkbox-list-problem-in-ie-values-saved-as-on-on-on-should-be-10-12-13